# How to load Images for a separate url threejs

Tags: javascript, url, three.js, constants, var

Total noob here. I'm learning threejs and I'm trying to load a texture to a cylinder from a separate directory on the web. Hopefully, someone can point out what is wrong with the code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry( 17, 17, 30, 35 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( );
            var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

            const myUrl = 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29174429/84787863-87516080-afff-11ea-9dca-3ed8d32d7b41.jpg'

            const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
            textureLoader.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"
            const myTexture = textureLoader.load(myUrl)

            cylinder.material.map(myTexture)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cylinder.material.map(myTexture)

It should be:

```
cylinder.material.map = myTexture;
```

`Material.map` is a property, not a method. Besides, the default value of `TextureLoader.crossOrigin` is already `anonymous`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited the code now, but just a black cylinder pops up. The texture doesn't load.

Comment: Have you added lights to your scene? Otherwise make a test by using `MeshBasicMaterial` instead of `MeshLambertMaterial`.

Comment: Yes I have. When I load the image from a local directory it works. I did some search and the problem seems to be the CORS.

Comment: Does it work with this texture? https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif